# Welches sprachliche Bild wird bei "du bist bei mir unten durch" aufgebaut?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Sicher, die Bedeutung ist: "ich mag dich nicht mehr" oder "ich hasse/verabscheue dich".

Doch auf welches sprachliche Bild bezieht es sich konkret?

Ist damit gemeint, man hat jemanden gegessen und ausgeschieden?

Comment: Limbo-Dancing? Nein, glaub' ich nicht.

Comment: Es wird eher für verspieltes Vertrauen, als Sympathie benutzt.

Comment: @userunknown Ist das die Antwort auf die Frage?

Comment: Nein, es ist eine Kritik der Behauptung, es würde  Hass und Abscheu ausgedrückt. Die sind zwar nicht ausgeschlossen, treffen es aber m.E. nicht.

Comment: @userunknown Das war eine rhetorische Frage, da nicht um Kritik der Erklärung gebeten wurde, erst recht nicht, wenn die Kritik lediglich auf Glauben fußt.

Comment: @PercivalJunghans: Wenn Du so empfindlich auf Kritik reagierst, werden wir wohl noch viel Spaß miteinander haben. ;)

Comment: In meiner Vorstellung, bezog sich das "unten" immer auf "unter meinen Ansprüchen", also "du wirst meinem Anspruch nicht gerecht", "du erfüllst das Mindestmaß in dieser Sache nicht"

Answer (score 3):

Eigentlich kein Bild - der Ausdruck steht schon im Grimm:

> UNTERDURCH, adv.; vgl.darunterdurch th. 2, 805 und oben sp. 1453, untendurch sp. 1450. eigentlich örtlich: das wasser ist hier u. gekommen, u. kriechen u. dgl. nwestd. umgangsspr.; dat rägende underdör; hê krôp dr underdör Doornkaat-Koolman 3, 469a; hê is dr underdör kamen 'er ist da unterdurch gekommen' und 'er ist von etwas herunterfallendem nicht getroffen' ebda. nl. 1onderdoor nl. wb. 10, 1274 ff. **übertragen: dao bist unnerdörch 'dabei kommst du zu kurz, bist der unterliegende' Danneil 231. in der sp. 1450 besprochenen ra. unterdurch sein, kommen: he is dr ganz underdör 'er ist ganz zurückgesetzt, steht ganz zurück, gilt oder kann nichts mehr' Stürenburg 297b;**